# NullPointerException error in stage icon javafx

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

The file "icon.png" is in the same folder as class. But if i just use (new Image("icon.png")) then it says java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found. But now after adding getClass().getResource... i'm getting this error. Here is my code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NewFile.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("icon.png").toExternalForm()));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Is the image in the resource folder along with the fxml and css files?

Comment: yes image is in the same folder along with fxml and css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NullPointerException error is caused due to `location of your image is not in the proper position`  your refer to something which not exist 
you can edit your post to show us your project construction
it should be somthing like that to work !

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!